# Account recovery from 2014

Tags: accounts

I set up an account in 2014. I have my username and recovery password but am unable to connect to the server to view my account using this link:

To enable account recovery, please verify your email address in your dashboard (https://launch.stellar.org/#/dashboard).

Thanks for the help!